# What is the best way to convert Dollars (Big Decimal) in Cents (Integer) in java?

Tags: java, integer, type-conversion, bigdecimal

I have to integrate my web application with a payment gateway. I want to input total amount in USD and then convert it into Cents as my payment gateway library accepts amount in Cents (of type `Integer`). I found that `Big Decimal` in java is best way for manipulation of currency. Currently I take input as say USD 50 and convert it to `Integer` like this:

```
BigDecimal rounded = amount.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
BigDecimal bigDecimalInCents = rounded.multiply(new BigDecimal("100.00"));
Integer amountInCents = bigDecimalInCents.intValue();
```

Is this the correct way of converting USD to Cents or I should do it in some other way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest which includes my points below is:

```
public static int usdToCents(BigDecimal usd) {
    return usd.movePointRight(2).intValueExact();
}
```

I'd recommend `intValueExact` as this will throw an exception if information will be lost (in case you're processing transactions above $21,474,836.47). This can also be used to trap lost fractions.

I'd also consider whether is it correct to accept a value with a fraction of a cent and round. I'd say no, the client code must supply a valid billable amount, so I might do this if I needed a custom exception for that:

```
public static int usdToCents(BigDecimal usd) {
    if (usd.scale() > 2) //more than 2dp
       thrown new InvalidUsdException(usd);// because was not supplied a billable USD amount
    BigDecimal bigDecimalInCents = usd.movePointRight(2);
    int cents = bigDecimalInCents.intValueExact();
    return cents;
}
```

Comment: This solution fails for negative value. For example, try -4.56, you will end up getting -455.

Comment: @YeshwanthKota tested it, that is not the case. Please elaborate. `System.out.println(usdToCents(BigDecimal.valueOf(-456, 2))); System.out.println(usdToCents(BigDecimal.valueOf(-4.56)));` both show `-4.56`

Comment: @weston: In the above response, you have tried BigDecimal.valueOf(-4.56) which makes the -4.56 a double value. Give a try with System.out.println("Value is BigDecimal: "+usdToCents(new BigDecimal(-4.56)));   and see that the response will be -455.

Comment: I think you've used different code to what I have provided as I get an exception. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Rounding necessary
 at java.math.BigDecimal.commonNeedIncrement(BigDecimal.java:4148)
 at java.math.BigDecimal.needIncrement(BigDecimal.java:4355)
 at java.math.BigDecimal.divideAndRound(BigDecimal.java:4330)
 at java.math.BigDecimal.setScale(BigDecimal.java:2470)
 at java.math.BigDecimal.longValueExact(BigDecimal.java:3090)
 at java.math.BigDecimal.intValueExact(BigDecimal.java:3147)
 at com.example.Main.usdToCents(Main.java:15)
`

Comment: https://ideone.com/UEF9ve Provide an example that fails and uses my code from the answer, not a modified version.

Comment: OK, this one ```public static int usdToCents(BigDecimal usd) {
    BigDecimal rounded = usd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
    BigDecimal bigDecimalInCents = rounded.multiply(x100);
    int cents = bigDecimalInCents.intValueExact();
    return cents;
}``` does fail, you're correct, I will remove it.

Comment: I added that one as how to work with what the OP had, but it was not the best. The best functions were at the top and bottom of the answer.

Comment: @weston: Thank you

Comment: @YeshwanthKota thanks to you for pointing it out. I'm surprised by that and I will look into it. I'd have thought `BigDecimal.valueOf(-4.56)` would work the same as `new BigDecimal(-4.56)` but I think there's an implicit cast to `float` in there somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

You should also consider minimizing `Round-off errors`.

```
int amountInCent = (int)(amountInDollar*100 + 0.5);
LOGGER.debug("Amount in Cents : "+ amountInCent );
```

This above solution might help you.