# How to convert dollar amount to cents in java?

Tags: java, currency, bigdecimal

I have the following program (taken from SO link [What is the best way to convert Dollars (Big Decimal) in Cents (Integer) in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398092/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-dollars-big-decimal-in-cents-integer-in-java)) which converts dollar to cents. However, the output is not as per my expectations.

**Current Output:**

```
12345
8
```

**Expected Output:**

```
12345
9
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    private static final BigDecimal x100 = new BigDecimal(100);
    static List<BigDecimal> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    static BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(123.45);
    static BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(0.09);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        nums.add(a);
        nums.add(b);
        for (BigDecimal usd : nums) {
            BigDecimal rounded = usd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
            BigDecimal bigDecimalInCents = rounded.multiply(x100);
            int cents = bigDecimalInCents.intValueExact();
            System.out.println(cents);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I imagine it's because the floating point value of 0.09 turns into 0.089999... and gets rounded down. Do you get the same behaviour if you use a string `"0.09"` ?

Comment: This (using a double to initialize a BigDecimal and then expecting exactness) is one of the most frequently made mistakes on this tag. Is there no question that can be referred to in such situations? This must already have many duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that doubles cannot represent all values. `9/100`, for example, can only be approximated. Try `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.09))`. You should get `0.0899999999999999966693309261245303787291049957275390625`. So you're rounding that down to 0.08 and then multiplying by 100.

Try `new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(0.09))`

**Edit:**
A better solution is to use `BigDecimal.valueOf(0.09)`, which is equivalent.

From the javadoc for [BigDecimal(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-):

> Translates a double into a BigDecimal which is the exact decimal representation of the double's binary floating-point value.
> ...
> When a double must be used as a source for a BigDecimal, note that this constructor provides an exact conversion; it does not give the same result as converting the double to a String using the Double.toString(double) method and then using the BigDecimal(String) constructor. To get that result, use the static valueOf(double) method.

And for [BigDecimal.valueOf(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-double-):

> Translates a double into a BigDecimal, using the double's canonical string representation provided by the Double.toString(double) method.
>
> **Note:** This is generally the preferred way to convert a double (or float) into a BigDecimal, as the value returned is equal to that resulting from constructing a BigDecimal from the result of using Double.toString(double).

Comment: or just `new BigDecimal("0.09")`

Comment: @puhlen: Indeed. Much better than to convert a double to a string and only then to a BigDecimal. Use strings to start with.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis The original question uses doubles as input so I thought it was appropriate to show how to work with them. If you're really starting with hard-coded values and have the option of changing them then you can just start with the number of cents and print it out without doing any calculations.

Comment: @user695022: OK, but if these values were, say, user input, or read in from a text file, using a string directly would be just as easy as reading the user input as a double.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

Use **strings**, not numeric literals.

```
new BigDecimal( "123.45" )
```

## Avoid floating-point

You implicitly introduced `double` type primitives into your code when constructing your `BigDecimal`.

```
new BigDecimal( 123.45 )  // <-- Passing `double` primitive
new BigDecimal( 0.09 )
```

While you thought you were passing `123.45` you were actually passing something more like `123.4500000000000028421709430404007434844970703125`. And instead of `0.09` you were passing something more like `0.0899999999999999966693309261245303787291049957275390625`.

You defeated the very purpose of using BigDecimal with currency which is to avoid the [**inherent inaccuracy of floating-point**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) types in determining their decimal fraction.

The Java types `float`, `Float`, `double`, `Double` all use [floating point technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_Point). Floating point technology trades away accuracy for speed of execution in calculations. Good for some gaming, graphics, and scientific/engineering purposes but bad for money.

[`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) does *not* use floating point technology. So the execution of calculations is much slower, but the results are accurate.

Solution: Avoid floating-point when constructing `BigDecimal`. Use strings.

```
new BigDecimal( "123.45" )
new BigDecimal( "0.09" )
```

Comment: Actually, the problem is that this is *binary* floating point technology. *Decimal* floating point (which is seldom implemented in hardware, but is specified by IEEE too) would not have that problem. Simple values like `123.45` and `0.09`would be exactly representable in those floating point types too. But hardly any language implements decimal floats, they simply use the *binary* floating point types that can be found in most hardware.